# Checking if article contain team names

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my articles to different teams depending on which teams it includes. At the moment i have following 3 tables:

```
teams(id, name, shortname)
news(id, title, text, url)
contain(team_id, news_id)
```

My question is then after following insert query

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO news (`title`, `url`, `image_url`, `news_text`, `referer_img`) VALUES ('$title', '$link', '$img', '$full_text_strip', 'test')");
```

I want to check the variable $full_text_strip contains one of the teams name or shortname and if yes it should create a new record in contains table with the just created news_id and the team_id. What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an untested SQL solution:

```
<?php
$query = "select name, shortname, id from teams";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $ids[$row['id'][] = $row['name'];
    $ids[$row['id']][] = $row['shortname'];
}
foreach($ids as $id => $teams) {
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        if(strpos($full_text_strip, $team) !== false) {
            //mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO news (`title`, `url`, `image_url`, `news_text`, `referer_img`) VALUES ('$title', '$link', '$img', '$full_text_strip', 'test')");
            echo 'We are inserting here because ' . $team . ' is present.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Tested code:

```
<?php
$title = 'this is input blue jays for the testing';
$ids = array(1 => array('blue jay', 'blues'), 2 => array('red sox', 'reds'), 3 => array('white sox', 'whites'));
foreach($ids as $id => $teams) {
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        if(strpos($title, $team) !== false) {
            echo 'Insert ' . $team . 'with id ' . $id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do i get the team id in the foreach loop?

Comment: Updated, I didn't see a column in your insert statement for that field.